# Validate date and time in sharepoint datetime picker control

Tags: datepicker

In my SharePoint 2010 visual web part, I have two SharePoint DateTime Picker controls which is used to add new appointment to the appointment schedule calendar.

Here, one datetime picker control is for `AppointmentStart` and other for `AppointmentEnd`. I need to check if there is already appointment existing for the selected period.

I need to validate the date and time selected in the selected changed event. I could get `OnDateChanged` event at server side but here i couldn't validate the time part. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Since its a visual webpart you can use .Net and JavaScript together to validate your DateTime Pickers controls, check this link out,

[datetime-control-in-net-and-javascript](http://sharepointcnetworldaks.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/datetime-control-in-net-and-javascript.html)

**EDIT**

Can you provide the code your using at the moment for validation for DateTime picker control as I think you can validate it using onDateChanged Server side event can't you.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code:

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl ID="dtFrom" runat="server" DateOnly="true" IsRequiredField="true"/>            
<asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="dtFrom$dtFromDate" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid date." Display="Dynamic"></asp:CompareValidator>
```